# CPU usage constantly high after upgrading from Postgres 9.5 to 9.6 to 10.6

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, cpu

I upgraded my RDS instance (db.t2.medium) from Postgres 9.5 to 9.6 couple of days back. Since the upgrade, the CPU usage was almost 100% all the time. This brought down my application. Presuming that the problem is with the 9.6 version, I did another upgrade to 10.6. It got better but still considerably higher than the CPU usage for the original 9.5 version.

I haven't changed the application code during the upgrade. How can I check the reason for the increased CPU usage and possibly fix it?

[image]

Comment: Don't presume, run a regular "ps -ef" and capture the output to be sure it's Postgres.

Comment: since it is an RDS instance, AWS would run only Postgres in the VM

Comment: Even so, Postgres consists of multiple processes.

Comment: Did you execute all steps as in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgupgrade.html ?

Comment: Did you run ANALYZE after the upgrade (or does RDS do that for you automatically)?

Comment: If running a database-wide ANALYZE (or `vacuumdb -Z`) doesn't fix the problem, then see https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: @GerardH.Pille we do not run the `pgupgrade` commands. RDS takes care of it. We just upgrade from their UI.

Comment: Can't you get Amazon to check it out?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes I have asked there too: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=298009

Comment: I see (or not). So, will you learn to live with it or execute some of the hints given here?

Comment: I have rolled back to 9.5 with a new RDS instance for now. Things are back to normal. Will need to investigate with a separate instance.

Comment: The Amazon cloud doesn't come with a silver lining?

Answer (score 42):

```
ANALYZE VERBOSE;
```

You need to run an [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) query on the whole database using the above command.

The issue is that the query plans postgres has generated are optimised for the previous version of postgres, when you do an RDS update it does not implicity regenerate these plans, this needs to be done manually (I'm sure there's a reason why AWS doesn't do this manually but I've really no idea why).

In my case I saw roughly a week of extremely high CPU usage, just as in your case, then after running ANALYZE my cpu dropped back to it's previous baseline. As you can see in the image below the upgrade (in my case from 9.4 - 9.5) was run on 11/27, the analyze query was run on 12/02.

(The VERBOSE is not strictly necessary but it's useful to be able to watch the progress of the command)

[image: Postgres RDS CPU usage over the course of a week]

Comment: I appreciate you.

Comment: 'God bless you' This saved us millions!

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: came here because my materialized views were dead slow after upgrading from postgres 11

Comment: Observed the same issue while upgrading from v9.6 to v13.3 on AWS RDS. Post the Analyse query, the CPU stabilized to the normal baseline.

Comment: This was affecting us as well. I can't believe this is not recommended by RDS. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this solution and the CPU usage dropped but just with a few connections. When replicated to production and many users started using the app CPU went to 100% again on the same instance config (t3.medium) and persisted after increase to t3.xlarge. I used `VACUUM ANALYZE`. Does anyone have more ideas?

Comment: @diegopso same issue observed in my case where we upgraded from 10.18 to 13.4. CPU usage increased to 99.9% without load but ANALYZE VERBOSE brought it down to around 12%. But queries which were taking 6-7 mins are now taking about 18 mins. What are the TODO's after upgrading.. Even i am not sure.